# ModalViewController in ios6

Tags: ios, ios6, modalviewcontroller

For a synch screen I made a ModalViewController on ios5. I used this code:

```
    synchViewController = [[SynchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SynchViewController" bundle:nil];
    synchViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController:synchViewController animated:YES];

    synchViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,SYNCHVIEW_WIDTH,SYNCHVIEW_HEIGHT);

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(screenBounds), CGRectGetMidY(screenBounds));
    synchViewController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(center.y, center.x);
```

The controller was designed in the xib file. This code worked.

Now under ios6 the presentModalViewController is depreciated. I changed the method, but now the modal view controller is totally displaced and got a wrong size.

How can I just have something like the iMessage login screen with the size of my designed xib layout?

EDIT:
It works with this code:
        synchViewController = [[SynchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SynchViewController" bundle:nil];

```
    synchViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    synchViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:synchViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    synchViewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    synchViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,
                                                     SYNCHVIEW_WIDTH,// Width
                                                     SYNCHVIEW_HEIGHT// Height
                                                     );


    synchViewController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, SYNCHVIEW_WIDTH, SYNCHVIEW_HEIGHT);
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(screenBounds), CGRectGetMidY(screenBounds));
    synchViewController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(center.y, center.x);
```

But only if I set animated to YES. When im trying to load it without an animation, its totally displaced again, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve by the following code?

```
synchViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,SYNCHVIEW_WIDTH,SYNCHVIEW_HEIGHT);
...
synchViewController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(center.y, center.x);
```

The size and position of a modal (presented) controller is defined by `modalPresentationStyle` and trying to change it will **never** work reliably.

If you want a different size of a presented controller, you have to write the controller by yourself (as a child view controller), insert it into the view hierarchy and block user interaction on the presenting controller.

However, I strongly advise to just use a native modal controller with the default size.

Comment: In ios5, this code worked well for me. And I also saw it on stackoverflow for a few times. Probably it was just something like a hack, I dont know :) What I dont understand with the modalPresentationStyle FormSheet - shouldnt it be possible to have a custom size of the view controller? Is the size fix? I really dont get the idea of the FormSheet.

Comment: @Andy Indeed, the size is fixed. There are hacks but mostly they don't work. I was actually using a similar hack on iOS 4 until iOS 5 came and it stopped working.